# Derive a polynomial function from a value table

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, functions, polynomials, systems-of-equations

i am stuck with the following excercise:

"The picture shows a value table of a polynomial function f.
Of which degree is f? Explain your choice.
Determine the function term of f.

$$
\begin{matrix}
- & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
f(x) & -1,66 & 0,75 & 2,333 & 4,083 & 9\\
f'(x) & 2,666 & 2 & 1,333 & 2,666 & 8\\
f''(x) & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & 8\\
\end{matrix}
$$

I will shortly give you my thoughts so far:
I suppose f is of degree 5, because there are two inflection points.
So my f(x) should be of form:
$$ 
f(x) = ax^5 + bx^4 + cx^3 + dx^2 + ex + f 
$$
$$ f'(x) = 5ax^4 + 4bx^3 + 3cx^2 + 2dx + e$$
$$ f''(x) = 20ax^3 + 12bx^2 + 6cx + 2d $$

Now i thought: we have 6 unknowns: a, b, c, d, e, f
Now we can choose 6 random equations from the value table to form a linear equation system. For example:

f(-1) = -1,66

f(0) = 0,75

f(1) = 2,333

f(2) = 4,083

f(3) = 9

f'(-1) = 2,666

Unfortunately i obtain solutions that do not deliver a reasonable f.
$$\begin{matrix}
a & \frac{107}{600000}\\
b & \frac{9923}{120000}\\
c & \frac{73}{120000}\\
d & \frac{59543}{120000}\\
e & \frac{199693}{100000}\\
f & 0,75\\
\end{matrix}$$

Can you guys help me?
Best regards,
Philipp

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Note that 
$$f''(x)=x^2-1$$

Comment: at least this holds at the points evaluated in the table. In fact, we can only give a lower bound for the degree of $f$

Answer (score 0):

We start by examining $f''(x)$. Note the second differences of $f''(x)$ are constant, as shown below:

$\begin{matrix}
x & -1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
f''(x) & 0 & -1 & 0 & 3 & 8\\
  &  & -1 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
  &  &  & 2 & 2 & 2
\end{matrix}$

Therefore, we claim $f''(x)$ can be modeled by a quadratic in the given interval. Setting $f''(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$, we note $f''(0) = c = -1$. Next, we form a system of equations: $f''(1) = a + b - 1 = 0, f''(2) = 4a + 2b - 1 = 3 \implies a = 1, b = 0$. Therefore, we say $f''(x) = x^2 - 1$.

Now, we integrate: $f'(x) = \int {f''(x) dx} = \int {x^2 - 1 dx} = \frac{x^3}{3} - x + C$. We use $f'(0) = 2$ to show that $C = 2$, so $f'(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} - x + 2$.

We again integrate: $f(x) = \int {f'(x) dx} = \int {\frac{x^3}{3} - x + 2 dx} = \frac{x^4}{12} - \frac{x^2}{2} + 2x + C_1$. We use $f(0) = .75$ to show $C_1 = .75$, so $f(x) = \frac{x^4}{12} - \frac{x^2}{2} + 2x + \frac{3}{4}$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the quick reply!
given we knew from the beginning that f was of degree 4.
Could we use equations derived from the value table, to solve the problem directly?

Comment: Definitely! Take $f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + f$. Note $f(0) = .75$ implies $f = .75$. We can then use the other four values to form a system of equations, which you can solve with substitution (or any method of your choosing). In general, if you have a n-th degree polynomial, having n points is enough to determine the exact coefficients of that polynomial (see if you can figure out why!). Hope this helps!